# Cannot access video files in folder created by PHP mkdir( )

Tags: php, html

I make use of PHP mkdir() function to create a folder in my server, then add a video file to this folder. However when I try to access this video using  tag in html5, the video couldn't be output. Below is a short summary of my code.

```
$parentDir = "path/to/directory";

   if(mkdir($parentDir) == false)
   { // Create the directory
        die('Problems creating directory.');
   }
   else
   {
       // upload output.mp4 and output.ogg to this directory
   }

<center>
       <video id="video" width="640" height="360" controls autoplay>
              <source src="path/to/directory/output.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
              <source src="path/to/directory/output.ogg" type="video/ogg">
              <p> HTML5 Video is required for this example </p>
       </video> 
</center>
```

Anyone has any idea on this?

Comment: check weather the video is in the folder when you use  form upload method, which browser are you using

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to post the error message you get? Or is this meant to be a _guessing game_?

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh the video will be created only after I press "submit" button once. so I will can only access the video in the second "submit" is it? btw I am using safari but I don't think this is the issue though.

Comment: please update your full code so that we help you better

Comment: @arkascha there is no error message. The video is shown on the page just that it is a blank video that keeps loading nothing.

Comment: There certainly _is_ an error message unless you uploaded an empty video. I suggest you either consult the error log file your http server writes or you open the development console of your browser to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server configuration it may be that mkdir($parentDir) is creating the directory without access permissions for your webserver to access the directory.

If you try access `path/to/directory/output.mp4` directly with your web browser and get an access denied error that would be the case.

If so Inside your `else` you could add `chmod("path/to/directory", 0755)` which would change the permissions for the directory to be world readable. (You might find you also need to do this to your file..)